# “The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() ” - Xamarin

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, watchkit

I am trying to build watch kit application and connect it with my iOS app, using xamarin framework.In HandleWatchKitExtensionRequest I use MarketRequestHandler class in order to bring data from API and display it on watchkit.
My Error is:
"The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]}
    Class: {ObjCRuntime.Class}
    ClassHandle (Foundation.NSError): 0xf09c10
    ClassHandle (Foundation.NSObject): 0xf09c10
    Code: 2
    DebugDescription: "Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=2 \"The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:]}"

This is my code:

```
public override void HandleWatchKitExtensionRequest
    (UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<NSDictionary> reply)  {   

        var json = new JsonParams ();
        var id="";
        nint taskID = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask (() => {
        });
        new Task (() =>{
            MarketRequestHandler mrk = new MarketRequestHandler();

            json.ckeys = new string[]{"P"};
            json.ids = new string[0];
            json.fields = new string[]{
                                         "LastDealTime",
                                         "LastDealDate"
                                      };
            json.index = 0;
            json.count = 300;

            var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (json);

            mrk.HandleRequest("market.get",jsonStr, (cb) =>{
                id = json.ids[0];
                reply (new NSDictionary (
                    "index", NSNumber.FromInt32 ((int)json.index),
                    "count", NSNumber.FromInt32((int)json.count),
                    "rzf", new NSString(id)
                ));
            });
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskID);
        }).Start ();                




    }
```

Watch interface

public override void Awake (NSObject context)
        {

```
        // Configure interface objects here.
        base.Awake (context);
        Console.WriteLine ("{0} awake with context", this);

        WKInterfaceController.OpenParentApplication (new NSDictionary (), (replyInfo, error) => {
            if(error != null) {
                Console.WriteLine (error);
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine ("parent app responded");
            // do something with replyInfo[] dictionary
            Label.SetText ( replyInfo.Keys[0].ToString() + " " + replyInfo.Values[0].ToString());
            label2.SetText(replyInfo.Keys[1].ToString() + " " + replyInfo.Values[1].ToString());
            label3.SetText(replyInfo.Keys[2].ToString() + " " + replyInfo.Values[2].ToString());
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I would guess that `id = json.ids[0];` throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException` since previously you set it to an empty array. That's why `reply` is never called. Perhaps you wanted to use `cb` instead of `json` in the callback handler.